# 2 datepickers on one input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this plugin](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm)

I have the following HTML and JavaScript:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Departure:</div>
        <div><input name="departureDateInput" value="#{bean.getFormattedFromDate()}" class="datepicker datepicker1"></input></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>Return:</div>
        <div><input name="returnDateInput" value="#{bean.getFormattedToDate()}" class="datepicker datepicker2"></input></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $input2 = $(".datepicker1").pickadate({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        min: 1,
        today: '',
        onClose: function() {
            var picker = $input.pickadate("picker");

            picker.set("select", this.component.item.select.pick);
            picker.open();

        }
    });

    var $input = $('.datepicker2').pickadate({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        min: 1,
        today: '',
        onClose: function() {
            $("#departureDateInput").text($input2.val());
            $("#returnDateInput").text($input.val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

The rendered result from the above is 2 input fields that each have their own datepicker. After selecting a date for the first input, the second one is automatically displayed, and the user can select a to date.

The functionality is fine, but I want to only show the user a single input that will get populated with the from and to dates, e.g. `13-06-2013 - 15-06-2013`

I have no idea how to go about implementing this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example, but using jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/kcCUD/10/

```
$(function() {
    var date1 = $('#date1');
    var date2 = $('#date2');
    date1.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");

            date2.datepicker("setDate", date);
            date2.datepicker( "show" );

        }
    });
    date2.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);

            date1.val(date1.val() + " - " + formattedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="date1" value="" size="30" />
<input id="date2" style="visibility:hidden" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I want to use the custom date picker, but I will see if I can use some of what you gave me to get the desired effect. If it works, I will mark this as the accepted answer and edit my question to show what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave them as two individual date pickers, but style them as if they were as one... I'E put them side by side and set the styling on them so the left one has no right border, and the right one has no left border.

This way, you'll still get both values passed as separate values once the form is submitted.

Comment: I've thought of doing this, but when the user selects the input he has to be prompted to select a new date range. Doing it this way would allow the user access to the 'to' date :(